# Why is "short thirty = 3 * 10" a legal assignment?

Tags: java, short, type-promotion

If `short` is automatically promoted to `int` in arithmetic operations, then why is:

```
short thirty = 10 * 3;
```

A legal assignment to the `short` variable `thirty`?

In turn, this:

```
short ten = 10;
short three = 3;
short thirty = ten * three; // DOES NOT COMPILE AS EXPECTED
```

as well as this:

```
int ten = 10;
int three = 3;
short thirty = ten * three; // DOES NOT COMPILE AS EXPECTED
```

does not compile because assigning an `int` value to a `short` is not allowed without casting as expected.

Is there something special going on about numerical literals?

Comment: `short thirty = 10 * 3;` is most probably replaced by `short thirty = 30;` by the compiler which is a valid statement then. (I'd have to look up the relevant JLS section though).

Comment: The compiler calculates `10 * 3` and initializes the variable with the result. In your non-working example the calculation happens at runtime where the JVM casts the short.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346587/java-char-to-byte-casting or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379983/type-casting-of-byte-and-int . However: Note that `final int ten = 10; final int three = 3; short thirty = ten * three;` compiles fine.

Comment: `If short is automatically promoted to int in arithmetic operations` -- that's not relevant.  Neither `10` nor `3` are shorts nor are they promoted, they're literals.

Comment: @MatthewRead: but even as literals, they have to get evaluated as a particular datatype, right? So is it true that `10` and `3` are evaluated as `int`s by the compiler?

Comment: @LarsH - Not always. `short s = 5` and `int i =10` are evaluated as `short` and `int` respectively. The problem comes when we have a *dangling constant*.  If `short s =  5;` ,  then `short s2 = s+5` won't work because the compiler thinks `s+5` would lead to an `int`. If `s` were `final ` (compile time constant),  then the compiler knows that `s+5` would fit in a `short` and thus it would be alllowed

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Because the compiler replaces `10*3` with 30 at *compile time* itself. So,effectively : `short thirty = 10 * 3` is calculated at compile time.

Try changing `ten` and `three` to `final short` (making them compile time constants) and see what happens :P

Examine byte-code using `javap -v`  for both verisions (`10*3` and `final short`). You will be able to see that there is little difference.

Ok, So, here is the byte code difference for different cases.

**Case -1 :**

> Java Code :
>       main() {
>           short s = 10*3;
>       }

Byte code :

```
stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: bipush        30  // directly push 30 into "s"
         2: istore_1      
         3: return
```

**Case -2 :**

```
public static void main(String arf[])  {
   final short s1= 10;
   final short s2 = 3;
   short s = s1*s2;
}
```

Byte code :

```
  stack=1, locals=4, args_size=1
         0: bipush        10
         2: istore_1      
         3: iconst_3      
         4: istore_2      
         5: bipush        30 // AGAIN, push 30 directly into "s"
         7: istore_3      
         8: return
```

**Case -3 :**

```
public static void main(String arf[]) throws Exception {
     short s1= 10;
     short s2 = 3;
     int s = s1*s2;
}
```

Byte-code :

```
stack=2, locals=4, args_size=1
         0: bipush        10  // push constant 10
         2: istore_1      
         3: iconst_3        // use constant 3 
         4: istore_2      
         5: iload_1       
         6: iload_2       
         7: imul          
         8: istore_3      
         9: return
```

In the above case, `10` and `3` are taken from the local variables `s1` and `s2`

Comment: liked `Try changing ten and three to final short` exercise :)

Comment: @SergeyPauk - That's really important in understanding compile time constants.. applies to all primitives (Strings as well..) :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I would suggest a better wording `you will see that there's no difference (between those two lines in the decompiled code)` cause isn't this your point?

Comment: Amusingly, this also means that `case 10*3:` and similar is legal in a switch construct.

Comment: And similarly in enum constructs. In fact, using stuff like 1 << 5 for bitfield enum constants is idiomatic.

Comment: @CeilingGecko - Yes it is legal. `case i : ` works when `i` is marked as `final short`

Answer (score 18):

Yes there is something special going on with the literal case: `10 * 3` will be evaluated at *compile* time. So you don't need an explicit `(short)` conversion for multiplied literals.

`ten * three` is not compile-time evaluable so therefore needs an explicit conversion.

It would be a different matter if `ten` and `three` were marked `final`.

Answer (score 2):

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33040977/1630604) adds the JLS section and some details about this behavior.

As per [JLS §15.2 - Forms of Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2)

> Some expressions have a value that can be determined at compile time.
>   These are constant expressions (§15.28).